# Plugin "@typescript-eslint" was conflicted

Tags: typescript-eslint

Plugin "@typescript-eslint" was conflicted between ".eslintrc.json" and ".eslintrc.json » eslint-config-react-app#overrides[0]".

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 2):

Similar issue occurred in my monorepo setup.

Adding "root": true in .eslintrc.js fixed my issue.

Comment: This didn't fix it for me.